# Restrict size of NSTextAttachment image

Tags: swift, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I am trying to insert an image in `UITextView`. I have used the following code.

```
extension TextView {
    func add(image: UIImage) {
        let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
        attachment.image = image

        attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

        let attString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)

        self.attributedText = attString
    }
}
```

The parent `UIViewController` calls `add(image: UIImage)`.

In `func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView)`, I save the **attributedText** in **CoreData** as a `Transforable` `NSAttributedString`. I use
`NSAttributedStringTransformer` for `Transformer`

[image]

The image's size is `40X40` when added. The image has also the same size when I dismiss the parent `UIViewController` and  present it back. However, if I quit the app and relaunch it, the image is not `40X40`.  It is larger than then UIScreen's size.

How to set size of the image to be `40X40` even after quitting the app?

Comment: Just resize the image when inserting it

Comment: @LeoDabus I do it in the add function. Could you please answer if it is not what you meant.

Comment: " if I quit the app and relaunch it" That's strange. You kill the app? How do you reconstruct the atttrtibuted then?

Comment: @Larme I updated my question. It is stored in Core Data.

Comment: Now it's clearer. It seems to be an existing issue that bounds aren't saved. Apparently, it's still there. You could add a custom atttributed to save the bounds, and when deserializing it from CoreData, read that property to apply the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

By setting attachment bounds, you are not resizing the actual image, just the display bounds. Looks like the attributed string transformer doesn’t serialize the bounds you set. You will have to either resize the image directly, or extend the transformer to add the bounds after deserializing from data.

**Edit:** I see that `NSAttributedStringTransformer` is not an Apple-provided transformer. So take a look at the source code and see why the bounds are not serialized properly.